# Stuck in writing HQL/MySQL query in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I am building Web services with Spring + Hibernate technologies and newbie to 
HQL/MySQL queries.

There is a challenging scenario I face

[image]

In `student_college` table,  **Student 1, 2, 3 and 4** are Studying in **College 1** and **Student 5,6,7 and 8** are studying in **College 2**

Also, In `friend_detail` table, Student 4 in College 1 and Student 8 in College 2 do not have any friends in the same college.

I would like to fetch Student 4 and Student 8 as list and they will be considered as suspicious persons because others in the same college have at least one friend in the same college

I am sure that it can be implemented through `for` loop but when the database reaches over 100k users, it is not feasible to hit the database multiple times for getting single set of result but no idea on how to start with writing query to this even after googling a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you need to write a `NOT EXISTS` query to check for students who don't have a friend relation on `friend_detail` table.

I think this can do the trick;

```
select * from student_college sc
where not exists (
select 1 from friend_detail fd where fd.friend1 = sc.student or fd.friend2 = 
sc.student
)
```